# q-Hermite polynomials

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, q-series

It is well known that the q-Hermite polynomials defined by $$H_n(\theta; q)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(q;q)_n}{(q;q)_k(q;q)_{n-k}}e^{i(n-2k)\theta}$$
are orthogonal in $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ with respect to the measure $(e^{i2n\theta},e^{-2in\theta}; q)_{\infty}d\theta=d\mu$.

Let me define now the modified q-Hermite polynomials $$H_n^{\lambda}(\theta; q)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(q;q)_n}{(q;q)_k(q;q)_{n-k}}\lambda^ke^{i(n-2k)\theta} $$.
Is it still true that the polynomials $\{H_n^{\lambda}(\theta; q)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are orthogonal with respect to some other measure $d\mu_{\lambda}$ in $[0, \pi]$? If Yes, which is their norm?

Comment: Just a comment: you call your modified $q$-Hermite polynomials polynomial, but I don't think they are. For $q$-Hermite polynomials you have a symmetry between $k \leftrightarrow n-2k$, so that $H_n$ becomes polynomial in $x = \frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})$. The $q$-Hermite polynomials are orthogonal on the unit circle as support. If you substitute $\cos(\theta)$ for $x$ you then see that you have support $[0,\pi]$. You can't do this if you insert this $\lambda^k$ in your modified $q$-Hermite polynomials.

Comment: If one defines $$H_n(x,y;q)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(q,q)_n}{(q,q)_k(q,q)_{n-k}}x^k y^{n-k}$$ you obtain usual q-Hermite polynomials by $H_n(e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta};q)$. And you obtain my modified q-Hermite polynomials by $H_n(\lambda e^{-i\theta}, e^{i\theta};q)$. Since $H_n(x,y;q)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ I called them polynomial, but I don't really care about them to be polynomial in the common sense.